# Base64.decode64 in ruby returning strange results

Tags: ruby, cgi, base64, decode

I'm having problems in decoding a string using Base64.decode64 in Ruby. As a test, I'm using this site that decodes strings in php: https://rnd.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/saml2debug/debug.php.

As a test, I'm using this string:

`fZJNT%2BMwEIbvSPwHy%2Fd8tMvHympSdUGISuwS0cCBm%2BtMUwfbk%2FU4zfLvSVMq2Euv45n3fd7xzOb%2FrGE78KTRZXwSp5yBU1hpV2f8ubyLfvJ5fn42I2lNKxZd2Lon%2BNsBBTZMOhLjQ8Y77wRK0iSctEAiKLFa%2FH4Q0zgVrceACg1ny9uMy7rCdaM2%2Bs0BWrtppK2UAdeoVjW2ruq1bevGImcvR6zpHmtJ1MHSUZAuDKU0vY7Si2h6VU5%2BiMuJuLx65az4dPql3SHBKaz1oYnEfVkWUfG4KkeBna7A%2Fxm6M14j1gZihZazBRH4MODcoKPOgl%2BB32kFz08PGd%2BG0JJIkr7v46%2BhRCaEpod17DCRivYZCkmkd4N28B3wfNyrGKP5bws9DS6PKDz%2FMpsl36Tyz%2F%2Fax1jeFmi0emcLY7C%2F8SDD0Z7dobcynHbbV3QVbcZW0TlqQemNhoqzJD%2B4%2Fn8Yw7l8AA%3D%3D`

The output should be:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="agdobjcfikneommfjamdclenjcpcjmgdgbmpgjmo" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2007-04-26T13:51:56Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" ProviderName="google.com" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://www.google.com/a/solweb.no/acs" IsPassive="true"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">google.com</saml:Issuer><samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified" /></samlp:AuthnRequest>`

But in Ruby I keep getting a strange output:

`}\222MO?0\206?H?\a??|\264???jRuA\210J????\233?LS\aۓ?8???IS*?K\257??}????\377\254a;??e|\022\247\234\201SXiWg????~?y~~6#iM+\026]غ'??6L:\022?C?;?J?$\234\264@\"(\261Z?~?8\255ǀ\n\rg??\214˺?u\2436??Z?i\244\255\224\001רV5\266\256?m??"g/G\254?kI???Q\220.\f\2454\275\216ҋhzUN~\210ˉ\270\274z??t???!?)\254????}Y\026Q?*G\201\235\256??\031\2723^#?b\205\226\263\005\021?0?ܠ\243΂_\201?i\005?O\017\031߆ВH\222\276??\241D&\204\246\207u?0?\212?
I\244w\203v??|ܫ\030\243?o
.\217(<\3772\233%ߤ?????X?h\264zg\vc\260\277? ??\236ݡ\2672\234v?Wt\025m?V?9jA鍆\212\263$?\270\376\177\030ù|\000`

The code I use is:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'base64'

Base64::decode64(CGI::unescape('fZJNT%2BMwEIbvSPwHy%2Fd8tMvHympSdUGISuwS0cCBm%2BtMUwfbk%2FU4zfLvSVMq2Euv45n3fd7xzOb%2FrGE78KTRZXwSp5yBU1hpV2f8ubyLfvJ5fn42I2lNKxZd2Lon%2BNsBBTZMOhLjQ8Y77wRK0iSctEAiKLFa%2FH4Q0zgVrceACg1ny9uMy7rCdaM2%2Bs0BWrtppK2UAdeoVjW2ruq1bevGImcvR6zpHmtJ1MHSUZAuDKU0vY7Si2h6VU5%2BiMuJuLx65az4dPql3SHBKaz1oYnEfVkWUfG4KkeBna7A%2Fxm6M14j1gZihZazBRH4MODcoKPOgl%2BB32kFz08PGd%2BG0JJIkr7v46%2BhRCaEpod17DCRivYZCkmkd4N28B3wfNyrGKP5bws9DS6PKDz%2FMpsl36Tyz%2F%2Fax1jeFmi0emcLY7C%2F8SDD0Z7dobcynHbbV3QVbcZW0TlqQemNhoqzJD%2B4%2Fn8Yw7l8AA%3D%3D'))
```

What could possibly be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the data is also deflated/compressed.

```
require 'zlib'
inflated=Base64::decode64(CGI::unescape('fZJNT%2BMwEIbvSPwHy%2Fd8tMvHympSdUGISuwS0cCBm%2BtMUwfbk%2FU4zfLvSVMq2Euv45n3fd7xzOb%2FrGE78KTRZXwSp5yBU1hpV2f8ubyLfvJ5fn42I2lNKxZd2Lon%2BNsBBTZMOhLjQ8Y77wRK0iSctEAiKLFa%2FH4Q0zgVrceACg1ny9uMy7rCdaM2%2Bs0BWrtppK2UAdeoVjW2ruq1bevGImcvR6zpHmtJ1MHSUZAuDKU0vY7Si2h6VU5%2BiMuJuLx65az4dPql3SHBKaz1oYnEfVkWUfG4KkeBna7A%2Fxm6M14j1gZihZazBRH4MODcoKPOgl%2BB32kFz08PGd%2BG0JJIkr7v46%2BhRCaEpod17DCRivYZCkmkd4N28B3wfNyrGKP5bws9DS6PKDz%2FMpsl36Tyz%2F%2Fax1jeFmi0emcLY7C%2F8SDD0Z7dobcyHbbV3QVbcZW0TlqQemNhoqzJD%2B4%2Fn8Yw7l8AA%3D%3D'))
zlib = Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS)
zlib.inflate(inflated)
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, this is exactly what was missing.

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea where you got the idea that that string of yours is a base64-encoded version of your XML. If you pass the first bit of it (`<?x`) through `Base64.encode64()` then `CGI.escape()`, you get:

```
PD94
```

at the start, which is *nothing* like your string. In fact, your first four characters "fZJN" are values 31, 25, 9 and 13 in base 64 so will give you:

```
011111 011001 001001 001101
```

then, grouping them in octets instead of sextets (I guess that's the right word):

```
01111101 10010010 01001101
   7D       92       4D
```

which are not the characters you're expecting to see.

Putting the whole string in gives you:

```
    PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4gPHNhbWxw
    OkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdCB4bWxuczpzYW1scD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRj
    OlNBTUw6Mi4wOnByb3RvY29sIiBJRD0iYWdkb2JqY2Zpa25lb21tZmphbWRj
    bGVuamNwY2ptZ2RnYm1wZ2ptbyIgVmVyc2lvbj0iMi4wIiBJc3N1ZUluc3Rh
    bnQ9IjIwMDctMDQtMjZUMTM6NTE6NTZaIiBQcm90b2NvbEJpbmRpbmc9InVy
    bjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpiaW5kaW5nczpIVFRQLVBPU1Qi
    IFByb3ZpZGVyTmFtZT0iZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSIgQXNzZXJ0aW9uQ29uc3VtZXJT
    ZXJ2aWNlVVJMPSJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tL2Evc29sd2ViLm5v
    L2FjcyIgSXNQYXNzaXZlPSJ0cnVlIj48c2FtbDpJc3N1ZXIgeG1sbnM6c2Ft
    bD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOmFzc2VydGlvbiI+Z29v
    Z2xlLmNvbTwvc2FtbDpJc3N1ZXI+PHNhbWxwOk5hbWVJRFBvbGljeSBBbGxv
    d0NyZWF0ZT0idHJ1ZSIgRm9ybWF0PSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FN
    TDoyLjA6bmFtZWlkLWZvcm1hdDp1bnNwZWNpZmllZCIgLz48L3NhbWxwOkF1
    dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4=
```

When you escape that, you get:

```
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4gPHNhbWxw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%0AbD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOmFzc2VydGlvbiI%2BZ29v%0AZ2xlLmNvbTwvc2FtbDpJc3N1ZXI%2BPHNhbWxwOk5hbWVJRFBvbGljeSBBbGxv%0Ad0NyZWF0ZT0idHJ1ZSIgRm9ybWF0PSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FN%0ATDoyLjA6bmFtZWlkLWZvcm1hdDp1bnNwZWNpZmllZCIgLz48L3NhbWxwOkF1%0AdGhuUmVxdWVzdD4%3D%0A
```

So, the bottom line is that you're getting junk from the decode because the data is not of the correct format.